# How to change MinGW-w64 path in VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, msys2

I just downloaded VS Code and I'm trying to execute C++ program on it.

I followed the [VS Code C++ Get Started Guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw), installed the latest version of MinGW-w64 via MSYS2 in drive `D:/` and did all the steps on [MSYS2 website](https://www.msys2.org/).

[image]

I added the environment path `D:\msys64\mingw64\bin`

[image]

I also installed the C/C++ extension.

[image]

However, when I try to execute C++ program, it shows this error message.

[image: Error message]

How do I change the compiler path to `D:\`?

Comment: There is a Compiler Path setting that you can modify. Open the Settings Panel though `Ctrl+,`, search for compiler path and try specifying the path there `D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe`

Comment: change the `command` parameter in `tasks.json` under `.vscode` folder.

Comment: @YK1 May I know the path of .vscode folder?

Comment: its in same folder as your cpp files, or whichever folder you opened VS code with as your workspace home